# getting wrong count when getting data from tables based on two dates

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In table the date will be saved as below, i need to generate reports in between dates using above column as `date_column>= (selected from date) and date_column <= (Selected to date)`

```
04/03/10 09:00:50.000000000 AM
```

below is my query

```
select * from table where  date_column>= (selected from date) and date_column <= (Selected to date) group by date_column desc
```

When i see the report the count of data in reports are different.

Selected date will be in this format `21/09/2014`

Comment: what is your to date and from date and what was you expecting and what rows are there in your table?

Comment: i should get data from table date range between two years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Date entry includes time stamp also thus you need to use

```
select * from table where  date_column between TO_CHAR(selected from date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') and TO_CHAR(selected to date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
group by date_column desc
```

With this it will include the timestamp in your where clause

You can use

```
 TO_CHAR(selected from date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

To format dates also.

Comment: between alway excludes last date rite for example between '1/12/2014' and 31/12/2014 in this query will not consider '31/12/2014' data. so i need data belongs to that date too

Comment: '1/12/2014' and '1/1/2015'

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the dates ranges and I will work a fiddle solution for you.